# Creating temp folder in Linux

Tags: r, linux, temp

I was using R installed on a Linux server using SSH. Everything was fine, but now I have been denied access to temp folder and if I am loading R it is giving error cannot create 'R_TempDir', as it can't create the temp folder.

Can you please tell me  how to create own local temp folder so that R can create temporary directory there ?

Comment: to use setwd, I have to first use R and I am not able to use R itself.

Comment: This worked for me: export TEMP=./

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set one of these environment variable :

> TMPDIR, TMP, TEMP:
>
> Consulted (in that order) when setting the temporary directory for the session: see tempdir. TMPDIR is also used by some of the utilities see the help for build

by doing for instance :

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```

[source](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/EnvVar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answers.
From what I understand,
I just thought that you could use `.bashrc` files in your /home/username/ directory

```
~# nano /home/username/.bashrc
```

You can put the command to create the folder inside this .bashrc file by just adding this line `mkdir /your/dir/path/yourDir`
This file is just like an autorun file which run everytime you upstart your linux server

But this is just working per user setting